# How do I use the 'generate' keyword in Verilog

Tags: fpga, verilog

I am trying to create a basic example of the use of the 'generate' keyword in Verilog, in [EDA Playground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/qUrY). However, it gives me errors that I don't understand.

```
module CrossBar( clkIn,
                 inputs,
                 switches,
                 outputs);
  
  parameter  NUM_IO          = 4;
  parameter  NUM_SWITCH_BITS = 2;
  
  input                             clkIn;          // These are 1-bit variable declarations
  input      [NUM_IO-1:0]           inputs;
  input      [NUM_SWITCH_BITS-1:0]  switches [NUM_IO-1:0];
  output reg [NUM_IO-1:0]           outputs;
    
  always @(posedge clkIn)   // Each time the input clock goes high,
    begin                   // execute the following code:

      genvar i;
      generate
        for (i=0; i<NUM_IO; i=i+1) begin
          outputs[i] = |(inputs & (4'b0001<<switches[i]));
        end
      endgenerate

    end        
endmodule
```

When I try to synthesize this, I get the following errors:

```
ERROR VCP2000 "Syntax error. Unexpected token: genvar[_GENVAR]. This is a Verilog keyword since IEEE Std 1364-2001 and cannot be used as an identifier. Use -v95 argument for compilation." "design.sv" 26  13
ERROR VCP2000 "Syntax error. Unexpected token: for[_FOR]." "design.sv" 28  12
ERROR VCP1023 "Compiler directive `timescale is not allowed inside a module." "testbench.sv" 10  11
```

It suggests adding the `-v95` option, but that just makes everything worse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `generate` loop would go outside of the `always`, but there is no need to complicate your code with a `generate`.  The `for` loop on its own is sufficient:

```
module CrossBar( clkIn,
                 inputs,
                 switches,
                 outputs);
  
  parameter  NUM_IO          = 4;
  parameter  NUM_SWITCH_BITS = 2;
  
  input                             clkIn;          // These are 1-bit variable declarations
  input      [NUM_IO-1:0]           inputs;
  input      [NUM_SWITCH_BITS-1:0]  switches [NUM_IO-1:0];
  output reg [NUM_IO-1:0]           outputs;
  
  integer i;
    
  always @(posedge clkIn)   // Each time the input clock goes high,
    begin                   // execute the following code:
        for (i=0; i<NUM_IO; i=i+1) begin
          outputs[i] <= |(inputs & (4'b0001<<switches[i]));
        end
    end  
  
endmodule
```

I replaced `genvar` with `integer`.

I also changed the assignment to nonblocking (`<=`), which is recommended for sequential logic.

Here it is on [EDA playground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/9x8Y)